# How to abort async() if timeout has elapsed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, std

I have a questions about async() function or any other way to solve my problem. I send to the server specified type of message and I wait for a specific 
response.
I have function receive() which waits for response from server. I call this function inside async().

Sample of code:

```
while (true) {
    future_receive = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {
        receive();
    });

    do {
        status = future_receive.wait_for(chrono::seconds(timeLimit));
        if (status == std::future_status::timeout){
            //if timeout, abort async() function
        }
    } while (status != std::future_status::ready);
}
```

What is my problem? In this case, if I get "timeout", async() function will work on, 
will wait until something comes, even if it will never come, and in the next cycle will be called again, 
and new thread will be created. How to avoid this?

How I can abort async() when "timeout" has elapsed. Maybe any other way without async() to solve this problem. I would like to use only the standard library of C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asynchronous thread has to cooperate and check whether it should continue working or give up, there is no portable way to force it to stop without its cooperation.

One way to do that is to replace the `receive()` call with a similar one that has a timeout, and have the thread give up after a timeout, or check a flag after a timeout to indicate whether to continue.

```
while (true) {
    std::atomic<bool> stop{false};
    future_receive = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {
        while (!stop)
          try_receive(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    });

    do {
        status = future_receive.wait_for(chrono::seconds(timeLimit));
        if (status == std::future_status::timeout){
            stop = true;
        }
    } while (status != std::future_status::ready);
}
```

Now the asynchronous thread will only block for up to a second, then will check if it's been told to give up, otherwise it will try receiving again.

If you're willing to sacrifice portability, something like this should work on platforms where `std::thread` is implemented in terms of POSIX threads:

```
while (true) {
    std::atomic<pthread_t> tid{ pthread_self() };
    future_receive = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {
        tid = pthread_self();
        receive();
    });

    do {
        status = future_receive.wait_for(chrono::seconds(timeLimit));
        if (status == std::future_status::timeout){
            while (tid == pthread_self())
            { /* wait for async thread to update tid */ }
            pthread_cancel(tid);
        }
    } while (status != std::future_status::ready);
}
```

This assumes that there is a Pthreads cancellation point somewhere in the `receive()` call, so that the `pthread_cancel` will interrupt it.

(This is slightly more complicated than I would like. It's necessary to store some known value in the atomic initially in order to handle the situation where the async thread has not even started running yet when the calling thread gets a timeout and tries to cancel it. To handle that I store the calling thread's ID, then wait until it's changed before calling `pthread_cancel`.)